# Add something after an argument?

Tags: java, string

Okay so I am writing a simple little StringBuilder, but I am just curious how I would add something after arguments. For example if I do:

```
args[0] = "how"
args[1] = "do"
args[2] = "i"
args[3] = "google"
```

How could I make it so the output is this: "how+do+i+google", but without a plus at the end of the last argument?

This is what I have so far.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    sb.append(args[i]).append(" ");
}

String allArgs = sb.toString().trim();
```

Comment: This is more a StringJoiner than a StringBuilder that you want to write

Comment: How could I do it inside of a StringBuilder though?

Comment: What is the problem? The code looks OK to me. Whatever works is always good code :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pre-JDK8 you can use [Guava's Joiner](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained):

```
return Joiner.on("+").skipNulls().join(args);
```

For JDK8, @chengpohi seems good enough, with little correction:

```
return String.join("+", args);
```

To extend OP code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    sb.append(args[i]);
    if(i != (args.length - 1)) {
        sb.append('+');
    }
}

String allArgs = sb.toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

In ***Java8***, you can use:

```
    String.join(",", args);
```

Comment: Problem with that is I am on java 7.

Comment: Guava Framework works also with java 7. And I didn't know this either. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the idiom used in JDK:

```
public String buildX(String...strings) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String string : strings) {
        sb.append(string.toString()).append(",");
    }
    if(strings.length > 0)
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: My only problem is how I have mine set, I updated my post if you would like to look.

Answer (score 0):

use following  code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("ho");
        StringBuffer str1=new StringBuffer("do");
        StringBuffer str3 = new StringBuffer("i");
        StringBuffer str4=new StringBuffer("google");
        System.out.println(str.append(str1).append(str3).append(str4));
            }
```

**Alternate**

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("ho");
    System.out.println(str.append("do").append("i").append("google"));
```

Comment: What is reason to create instance of StringBuffer for every token?

Answer (score 0):

There are two other approaches

1. Guava framework

   Joiner.on("+").join(Arrays.asList(strings));
2. Use JDK8 Stream Api

   Arrays.asList(strings).stream()
     .collect(Collectors.joining("+"))

Answer (score 0):

Simple Modification to your existing code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int i = 0;

for (; i < args.length -1; i++){
    sb.append(args[i]).append(" ");
}
sb.append(args[i]);
String allArgs = sb.toString();
```